# delarray and colortbl issue

Tags: incompatibility, arrays, colortbl

There seems to have a compatibility issue between the `colortbl` and `delarray` packages because when compiling the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{delarray,colortbl}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}({ll})
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

pdfLaTeX complain about a

```
missing \right. at \end{array}.
```

When I remove the `colortbl` package, then it works as normal. I've got old TeX sources with a lot of matrices defined with the help of `delarray`. I discovered this problem because I wanted to put some colors on these documents.

Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It's hard to get package authors to coordinate with each other....

Comment: I've got the same problem when playing tennis :-)

Answer (score 7):

oops, sorry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{delarray,colortbl}
\makeatletter
\def\endarray{\crcr \egroup  \egroup\@arrayright  \gdef\@preamble{}\CT@end}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}({ll})
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: wow I didn't expect a quick answer from the package's author himself ! Many thanks for your impressive work on LaTeX.